# LM78H05K How to use

Tags: voltage-regulator, 5v, pinout, 7805

I have bought the LM78H05K 5 V voltage regulator ,  for the 5v output.
My input voltage is 17 V DC. but unfortunately this component is in different shape. I have uploaded the image of the module. I read the datasheet but with that instructions i am not be able to get 5 v output , output is showing me 2 v only. What and where i am connecting it wrong , can anyone help.
My basic question is how to use it.  Also the ground is just shown in the plain area , is it must be sticked to the plain area shown in the image.
[image: Product Description Image]

Datasheet [link](http://www.jameco.com/Jameco/Products/ProdDS/51246NSC.pdf) here.

Comment: Post your schematic, are you using input / output capacitors / you did not include a link to the LM78 you are using but the TI one I looked at is only rated for 100mA, are you trying to draw too much current?

Comment: The photo that you have shown is a 78H15K. What is printed on the regulator that you have?

Comment: thanks for the immediate response. 
i am directly connecting an adapter which is giving 17v Dc to input pin , without any capacitors. i have bought this LM7805 module for 3A current capacity. also i am not connecting any load to it for now.

Comment: Please edit your post, include the information in your comment, and include a link to your datasheet.

Comment: h4d0452a -  LM78h05k

Comment: added the datasheet in post,

Comment: You should use a "TO-3 mounting kit" to attach the regulator to the heatsink. You will also need a small amount of electrically-insulating thermal compound - apply a thin layer of it to both sides of the mica washer. The kit will come with a small tag to attach the ground lead.

Answer (score 2):

That's just a TO-3 case.  If you look at the bottom, you see two pins sticking up.  These are clearly labeled in the diagram you show.  The case is the third terminal.  This kind of package is intended to be mounted against a heat sink.  That's what the holes at the ends are for.  Generally you'd make a connection using one of the screws thru the holes.

As far as using the terminals in a circuit, that really must be in the datasheet.  We shouldn't have to tell you very basic stuff like that.

### Added

You don't *have to* use a heatsink just to connect to the device.

However, if its dissipation will be more than 1 W or so, you'll want to keep the device cool somehow, else it will keep going into thermal shutdown.  You say the input is 17 V, the output 5 V, which means the regulator is dropping 12 V.  At 1 A output, it will dissipate 12 W, which definitely requires a heatsink.

Step back a few levels and explain what you really want to accomplish.  Linearly regulating 17 V to 5 V at 1 A is probably not the best answer.

Comment: thanks for the immediate response. 
i am very very newbie to the electronics, i just googled the heatsink with 7805 . i will buy and try with heat sink. thanks,

Comment: What will the output current be?

Comment: around 1A i will be using.

Comment: It will cause 12W power dissipation on the device (max 150C for K version, operating up to 70C). Look here for some interesting discussion - fake regulators, replacement with switching regulator - http://www.vcfed.org/forum/showthread.php?55004-LM78H05K-fakes

Comment: @Anonymous : helpful info it is , i can use the resistors in series, but in the datasheet only they have not shown which hole is for what purpose.

Comment: Connection diagram on page 1 clearly shows GND, input and output. And your dealing with this regulator may just be useless as you may not get desired result at the end (5V 1A output) - I would consider it first, before going to circuits and layouts.

Comment: I was using 7805C 5v voltage regulator, The power supply circuit i have is giving 17V DC and 5A capacity after converting from AC TO DC , the circuit or whatever project i am going to attach further will be consuming around 1A current with 5v as an input.
I am just trying to achieve 5v output , but with 7805C when current crosses Above 1.5A it burns , hence using a voltage regulator with more current capacity.

Comment: @Anonymous : the diagram on page 1 have shown the image but they are not pointed to the holes instead of a plain area on the module.

Comment: The "plain area" is usually called the "case". A quick way to connect a wire to it is with a screw and nut through one of the holes.

Comment: @Karm: They point to the bulk of the case, which is all one contact.  This really should be obvious just by looking at it, since it's all one piece of connected metal.

Answer (score 0):

Found the connection , thanks a lot everyone for the immediate response.

[image]

Comment: How is this not exactly what you posted in the question in the first place?